# JNA Pointer Pass

Tags: java, jna

test.h

```
struct test{

char  *pCarrierName;

}
```

And Equivalent JNA Syntax is-

```
public static class test extends Structure {

    public Pointer pCarrierName;    
      public test( Pointer pCarrierName) {

                super();     

                this.pCarrierName = pCarrierName;


            }
}
```

Now how can i instantiate this "test" class? Actually i want to do following this type of call-

```
public static void main(String[]args){
       test ob = new test("AIR GAS");
}
```

Comment: This is not the right way to to use JNA...what is your .DLL (Windows) or .so (Linux) library name that you want JNA to bind to?

Comment: When i create Object using this statement test ob = new test("AIR GAS") it throws error because here i passed Java String and JNA function accepts Pointer argument.I want to know how can i pass Pointer parameter.

Comment: `char* pCarrierName` can be represented as `char[] pCarrierName`. So, in JNA, you can just type `public char[] pCarrierName`

Answer (score 0):

The structure field should be of type String; then you can initializer the structure and its field with the original String argument.